# Error after migrating AjaxControlToolkit 1.x to 3.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm getting this error after I migrated AjaxControlToolkit 1.0... to 3.5 recently:

> Extender control 'AlwaysVisibleLoading' cannot extend
>   'UpdateProgress1'. Extender controls of type
>   'AjaxControlToolkit.AlwaysVisibleControlExtender' cannot extend
>   controls of type 'System.Web.UI.UpdateProgress'

Couldn't get helpful references on this so far. Anyone?